# Input device that mimics wiimote to use as mouse?

Tags: mice

I'm looking for an input device that mimics how the Wii/Wii-U operate using the sensor-bar.

I need it as a secondary mouse. So, a pointer of sorts that isn't just a clicker would be nice. Something that will let me move my mouse without having to actually drag it on something material.

Not sure if anything like that exists though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick search using the terms "gyro mouse," as devices of your description would have some form of internal solid state gyroscope to sense movement. One of the results can be found [on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001KEGULI) with reasonably good reviews. I did not perform an exhaustive search, but I'd be confident to suggest that there would be similar products from other manufacturers.

[image]

Another option which may be more challenging to implement while at the same time, rather high-techy/geeky/sci-fi implemtation is called the [Leap Motion Controller](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HVYBWQO), also from Amazon. It uses a set of detectors in a rectangular puck over which one waves and/or places one's hands. Specific motions can be user-programmed for just about anything. I'm not aware of similar devices of this nature but then again, it's not your primary focus.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Logitech MXAir. I've been using mine since roughly 2007 and I love it. 8 programmable buttons and a touch surface for delightful scrolling. They don't make it anymore, so you'd have to get it off eBay.